# MAC OSX: Cannot run multiple local domains

Tags: macos, localhost, virtualhost

i am trying to add another local domain to my mac osx:

No matter what i do when visiting say 'domainnumber2.dev' it always displays the first host in my list.

If i swop them around in my httpd-vhosts file then i get the domainnumber2.dev site.
How can i run multiple localhost site on my mac.

I have a simple set up as below:

```
  <VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName mydomain.dev
     ServerAlias mydomain.dev
     DocumentRoot "/Users/UserName/Sites/mydomain/"
  </VirtualHost>

  <VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName mydomainTwo.dev
     ServerAlias mydomainTwo.dev
     DocumentRoot "/Users/UserName/Sites/mydomainTwo/"
  </VirtualHost>
```

I have also had the more details set up adding the below for both

```
  <Directory "/Users/UserName/Sites/mydomain/">
     DirectoryIndex index.php
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
     AllowOverride all
     Order allow,deny
     allow from all
  </Directory>
```

In my hosts file i have:

```
  ##
  # Host Database
  #
  # localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
  # when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
  ##
  127.0.0.1 localhost
  255.255.255.255   broadcasthost
  ::1             localhost 
  fe80::1%lo0   localhost
  127.0.0.1 mydomain.dev
  127.0.0.1 mydomainTwo.dev
```

which ever VirtualHost is first is the site that is served up

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across this same problem...

In your httpd-vhosts.conf file (/private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf after showing hidden files) add the following for each domain...

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mysubdomain.dev
    CustomLog "/root/to/site/logs/mysubdomain.dev-access_log" combined
    ErrorLog "/root/to/site/logs/mysubdomain.dev-error_log"
    DocumentRoot "/root/to/site/mysubdomain.co.uk"
    <Directory "/root/to/site/mysubdomain.co.uk">
        DirectoryIndex index.php
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride all
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Then restart apache. Everything else you have seems to be the same as my setup.

Make sure you have the correct permissions to be able to write the log files etc too.

Comment: Thanks for this unfortunately cannot test any more as moved onto VM's via Vagrant etc now as better to mimick my live servers etc  Thanks again but will try once and if i set up like it again.